# How to perform a fast ray cylinder intersection test?

Tags: c++, raycasting, intersection

I need an algorithm in c++ to get the intersection point of a line if there is an intersection. My cylinder is defined by a 3d vector center point, a float height and radius. I don't need to take rotation into consideration at all so I don't need any rotation parameters.

The only one found similar to my needs was this: https://github.com/iceman201/RayTracing/blob/master/Ray%20tracing/Cylinder.cpp
but after implementing it gave me wrong results. All the other ones I found used weird arguments that weren't even close to my desire. So I am pretty stuck now.

Comment: When you say "fast"... this would come down to micro-optimsations. Because essentially no matter what code you find, the algorithm will always be: translate the ray into cylinder space, rather than vice versa. Once the ray has been translated into (axis aligned) cylinder space, do a broadphase ray-circle test (2D); and then if broadphase evaluates to true, narrowphase checking whether that potential hit *is* a hit in 3D, i.e. are the broadphase intersection points of the ray within the +ve & -ve half-height range around your cylinder centre.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First we'll subtract the cylinder center from the ray origin, to translate our whole problem to be centered at (0, 0, 0).

**Case 0: Inside**

First, check if the ray origin is inside the cylinder from the start.

$$\text{origin}_x^2 + \text{origin}_z^2 \leq \text{radius}^2 \quad \text{and}\quad
-\frac {\text{height}} 2 \leq \text{origin}_y \leq \frac {\text{height}} 2$$

If so, it's conventional to return no hit (we only count hits going into the cylinder). Though you could instead invert the following cases to check for a hit exiting the cylinder.

**Case 1: Above / Below**

If our shifted origin is above \$\frac {\text{height}} 2\$ or below \$-\frac {\text{height}} 2\$, then we check whether its direction takes it closer to the cylinder:

$$\text{origin}_y \times \text{direction}_y < 0 ?$$

If it does not, we know the ray is too high/low to ever hit the cylinder, and we can early-out with no hit.

Otherwise, we can advance the ray to the time \$t\$ when it crosses the plane of the cylinder's top (or bottom):

$$t_{\text{plane}} = -\frac {\text{origin}_y - \text{sign}(\text{origin}_y)\frac {\text{height}} 2} {\text{direction}_y}$$

The ray's position at that time is \$\vec p_1= \vec {\text{origin}} + t_\text{plane} \cdot \vec {\text{direction}}\$

If that point is inside the cylinder's radius,

$${p_1}_x^2 + {p_1}_z^2 \leq \text{radius}^2$$

Then we have a hit against the top/bottom cap of the cylinder, with a vertical collision normal.

If not, we can proceed as though the ray had started somewhere beside the cylinder, rather than above/below:

**Case 2: Beside**

Next we'll check if the ray hits the circle. For that we want to know the earliest positive time \$t\$ at which...

$$||\vec {\text{origin}} + t \cdot \vec {\text{direction}}|| = r\\
(\vec {\text{origin}} + t \cdot \vec {\text{direction}})^2 = r^2\\
t^2 \cdot \text{direction}^2 + t \cdot 2(\vec {\text{origin}} \cdot \vec {\text{direction}}) + \text{origin}^2 - r^2 = 0$$

You can solve this with quadratic formula. Choose the smallest positive solution, and call it \$t_\text{circle}\$. If there is no positive real solution, return no hit.

Then, as we did with case 1, find the position at that time: \$\vec p_2= \vec {\text{origin}} + t_\text{circle} \cdot \vec {\text{direction}}\$

Now we check whether that's on our cylinder, or if it missed:

$$| {p_2}_y| < \frac {\text{height}} 2 ? $$

If the hit is within this height range, then we have a hit, with collision normal parallel to \$\vec p_2\$. Otherwise, we miss the cylinder and return no hit.

---

If you do find a hit, add the cylinder center back to the hit position \$\vec p_1\$ or \$\vec p_2\$ to get the hit position in world space.